# convert a tool from 32bit to 64bit in python

Tags: python, executable

i am using a tool which is build in 32bit of 2.7 version of python. It uses several libraries. I want to make that .exe  file into 64 bit binary. I got the equivalent 64 bit libraries but don't know from how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed as following:

1. Run the test in the libraries you want to port on a 64bit machine to make sure it does what you want.
2. You can use [py2exe](http://py2exe.org) to convert it into a windows binary.

Note: if orignal libraries are doing any native calls it can behave strange.

Comment: i can get 64 bit equivalent libraries so i guess the behaviour will be the same and  that py2exe gonna convert it into 64 bit. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @kush py2exe indeed have some limitations but under most of the condition it works well, you must give it a try and hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: i am using microsoft visual c++ compiler for python and i dont wana change the compiler. what i found out that this compiler can also execute 64 bit programs. so no issues with compiler. libraries will be the same for 32bit and 64 bit. i setup environemnt of compiler as x64. but still unable to proceed

Comment: I did that by changing some libraries from 32 bit to 64 bit in my virtualenv. It was bit easy